# HLSL Multi-texturing with Fog problem in Direct3D

Tags: c++, hlsl, texture-mapping, shader

I am trying to implement a multi-texturing and fog on some terrain in my demo, but apparently i am going wrong somewhere because the texturing is not visible, the only thing that is being rendered is the fog color in the terrain.

No sign of texturing whatsoever.

Here is the fx file:

```
//------------------------------------
//Stuff for the Terrain
uniform extern float4x4 MatVP;
uniform extern float3  SunPos;
uniform extern texture Tex0;
uniform extern texture Tex1;
uniform extern texture Tex2;
uniform extern texture TexGS;
uniform extern float3  EyePos;


//------------------------------------

sampler sTex0 = sampler_state
{
    Texture = <Tex0>;
    MagFilter = LINEAR;
    MinFilter = ANISOTROPIC;
    MaxAnisotropy = 8;
    MipFilter = LINEAR;
    AddressU = WRAP;
    AddressV = WRAP;
};

sampler sTex1 = sampler_state
{
    Texture = <Tex1>;
    MagFilter = LINEAR;
    MinFilter = ANISOTROPIC;
    MaxAnisotropy = 8;
    MipFilter = LINEAR;
    AddressU = WRAP;
    AddressV = WRAP;
};
sampler sTex2 = sampler_state
{
    Texture = <Tex2>;
    MagFilter = LINEAR;
    MinFilter = ANISOTROPIC;
    MaxAnisotropy = 8;
    MipFilter = LINEAR;
    AddressU = WRAP;
    AddressV = WRAP;
};
sampler sTexGS = sampler_state
{
    Texture = <TexGS>;
    MinFilter = LINEAR;
    Magfilter = LINEAR;
    Mipfilter = POINT;
    AddressU = WRAP;
    AddressV = WRAP;
};

const float3 FogColor = {0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f};
const float  FogStart = 10.0f;
const float  FogRange = 200.0f;

struct vOut {
    float4 PosH            : POSITION0;
    float2 cTexTiled    : TEXCOORD0;
    float2 cTexNonTiled : TEXCOORD1;
    float shade            : TEXCOORD2;
    float FogSaturate    : TEXCOORD3;
};

//------------------------------------
vOut VS_Def(float3 PosW : POSITION0
 , float3 NormW : NORMAL0
 , float2 cTex : TEXCOORD0)
{
    vOut V = (vOut)0;

    V.PosH = mul(float4(PosW, 1.0f), MatVP);
    
    float3 SunVec = normalize(SunPos - EyePos);
    V.shade = saturate(max(0.0f, dot(NormW, SunVec)) + 0.25f);
    
    float Dist = distance(PosW, EyePos);
    V.FogSaturate = saturate((Dist - FogStart)/FogRange);

    V.cTexTiled = cTex * 16.0f;
    V.cTexNonTiled = cTex;
    return V;
}

float4 PS_Def(float2 cTexTiled : TEXCOORD0
, float2 cTexNonTiled : TEXCOORD1
, float shade : TEXCOORD2
, float FogSaturate : TEXCOORD3): COLOR
{
    float3 Tex0 = tex2D(sTex0, cTexTiled).rgb;
    float3 Tex1 = tex2D(sTex1, cTexTiled).rgb;
    float3 Tex2 = tex2D(sTex2, cTexTiled).rgb;
    float3 TexGS= tex2D(sTexGS,cTexNonTiled).rgb;

    float inv = 1 / (TexGS.r + TexGS.g + TexGS.b);
    Tex0 *= TexGS.r * inv;
    Tex1 *= TexGS.g * inv;
    Tex2 *= TexGS.b * inv;
    float3 TexColor = (Tex0 + Tex1 + Tex2) * shade;
    float3 FinalColor = lerp(TexColor, FogColor, FogSaturate);

    return float4(FinalColor, 1.0f);
}
    

//-----------------------------------
technique DefTech
{
    pass p0 
    {        
        VertexShader = compile vs_2_0 VS_Def();
        PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 PS_Def();
        
    }
}
```

as you can see, the fog color is gray, and that is all I am getting. It is very depressing.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be, that FogSaturate is too high, or in other words, FogRange is too low, so the lerp call always returns FogColor. Try to set FogRange higher and see if it helps.

Robert

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing matVP is your (view matrix) * (your projection matrix) however you will need a World, View and Projection matrix to map the location of the terrain correctly. (In other words, right now the location in which you draw your terrain at the moment is completely wrong. That's why you can't see anything).

Try passing:

```
pEffect->SetMatrix( "MatVP", &(matW*matV*matP));
```

It should work.